# Using a loop in PHP to store div ID's into an array

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I am trying to build a page using laravel where users select from a list their preferred options from a list of courses they can enroll in. I have defined a div tag which should hold these values:

```
<div class="container" id="selectedCourses"></div>
```

Currently, there is a javascript function I use to add and remove courses given user clicks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // functions for adding selected element to top
    function addCourse(subject, courseID) {
        // adds selected course to top
        var l = document.getElementById('item' + subject + courseID);
        if(l.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(255, 255, 255)" || l.style.backgroundColor === "") {
            var p = document.getElementById('selectedCourses');
            var newCourse = document.createElement('button');
            newCourse.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-outline-primary');
            //set id here
            newCourse.setAttribute('id', 'selected'+subject+courseID);
            newCourse.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeCourse(this.id);');
            newCourse.innerHTML = subject + ' : ' + courseID;
            p.appendChild(newCourse);

            // recolors selected course in list
            l.style.backgroundColor = '#3399ff';
            return;
        } 
        if(l.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(51, 153, 255)") {
            removeCourse('selected'+subject+courseID);
            l.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        }
    }

    // function for removing select element from top
    function removeCourse(elementID) {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
        var id = element.id.slice(8);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        var p = document.getElementById('item' + id);
        p.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    }
</script>
```

I've also defined a button that I want to use in order to enroll the user with their selected courses.

However, problem is I do not understand how to grab all the courses in the div tag after they have been added. I believe I need some php loop in the div tag that goes through each ID but I do not know what I'm iterating on or how to reference these values. I need this to be passed into a function I've defined for a button so I can update the database through the controller. Any suggestions?

Comment: For you to have contact between `PHP` and javascript you either: 1.submit the data; 2. Do an Ajax request; Can you provide any of those? Or do you have any of them?

Comment: Also if you are storing all the desired courses in `javascript` to send all at once at the end, you will need an array in `javascript` to hold on to that information so you can post it later on (If you go through the Ajax approach)

Comment: Currently you're not including any of your PHP code in the question - do you have PHP, or do you want us to write PHP?